# "An unexpected System Error has occured. Additional details have been logged for yor Administrator."

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am getting this error while connecting to Dashboard Designer in Performance Point Server 2010.

Also when i check with windows administrator logs, i get following:

```
An unexpected error occurred.  Error 19106.

Exception details:
System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The requested service, 'http://win-engffdbgdb:32843/16cf7edf9c81417b97f549e23f57eb5f/PerformancePointService.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.IBIMonitoringServiceApplication.GetListItems(String listUrl)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationProxy.<>c__DisplayClasse8.<GetListItems>b__e7(IBIMonitoringServiceApplication channel)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.BIMonitoringServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(CodeBlock codeBlock)
```

Answer (score 2):

That hotfix is not relevant anymore, it's been applied to the most recent rollups and VS2010 service pack 1. For me to fix this annoying error, I had to stop the service on the server, and start it again.

1. Go to Central Admin
2. Manage services on this server
3. PerformancePoint Application, click Stop
4. Accept warning to disable it
5. Once disabled, wait a few minutes, then start it again.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like its trying to activate the PerformancePointService automatically, when you connect with the Dashboard designer.

It might be worthwhile to activate it manually, and see what occurs.

In addition can you look at the SharePoint diagnostic logs, and see if there is any more information there?

Comment: Go to your Central Administration page, then services on server, and click start next to PerformancePoint Service.

Answer (score 1):

Grant access to the account you use for performance point service application

```
$w = Get-SPWebApplication -identity <web application>
$w.GrantAccessToProcessIdentity("<service account>")
```

Not to forget to configure the performance point services to use this as Unattended Service Account to access data sources:
Central Admin > Manage Service Applications> PerformancePoint Services

> PerformancePoint Service Application Settings 
>   Key in the account and password and OK.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had to work with PerformancePoint updating the credentials, at one point I had the same error message. It finally came out all right after I follow these steps, I know it should be already like this in your farm, but it may worth the shoot just to make sure is not an Authentication issue!!

http://www.slideshare.net/slideshow/embed_code/31958482

Hope it helps!!